# Why my post's thumbnail is not showing up?

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I have created a post with featured image from the ***Add New Post*** section, and now I want to retrieve the post with it's thumbnail , summary and the title.
The other fields are displayed just fine (title, and Summary) the way I want, however nothing can be retrieved for the thumbnail. Here is the code I'm using :

```
<?php
    $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'order'=> 'DESC','category' => 'watch', 'orderby' => 'post_date','offset' => 1, );
            $postslist = get_posts( $args );
            foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post); ?> 

            <td class="leftBoxes">
                <!--IMAGE- THIS IS the Problem -->
            <div class="imgMargin"> <?php  get_the_post_thumbnail(); ?> </div>

           <br>
            <div class="boxScrollsBlogsView">
            <h2><?php the_title(); ?> </h2>
            <P> 
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?> 
            </P>
            </div>

            </td>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
```

I added this line to the ***function.php*** as well

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
```

and I can see the image when I click on single-post view, to check if it is added to the db or not.

But it just doesn't come up in the custom page that I've created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are supposed to `echo` it as the functions return strings. E.G.:

```
<div class="imgMargin"> <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(); ?> </div>
```

Try this one:

```
 <div class="imgMargin"> <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID); ?> </div>
```

Comment: even when I do echo the code in View Source doesn't show anything it comes out as this : 

http://oi42.tinypic.com/ic4gft.jpg

Comment: thanks for you both tries, but it still prints out nothing ! Does that mean I have a problem with using _Thumbnail_ ?

Comment: Well, I think now manual would come handy http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail

Comment: Thanks Jari for your time, to be honest I looked at the manual very carefully from the beginning. I will look up some other snippets now, I feel I'm doing something else wrong causing it not to show up.

Comment: Well there are no better way to explain my case unless by saying, ***I'm a Newbie*** , but I guess that is just one way to learn things!

I misunderstood how the offset works, I have been calling the wrong blog all the time that has no thumbnail. This worked just fine 

    `<div class="imgMargin"> <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?> </div> `

I only had to change the offset in the query :

  

    `$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'order'=> 'DESC','category' => 'watch', 'orderby' => 'post_date','offset' => 0 );`

now I have to change the way I get the blog, because its wrong!

Comment: Ah, it's fine :) I'm glad you have found a solution!